# What is the required visibility of an action method in iphone responder chain?

Tags: iphone, events, methods, visibility

In a UIViewController subclass I create a bar button item that fires an event up the responder chain:

```
UIBarButtonItem* editListsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:@selector(edit)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editListsButton;
[editListsButton release];
```

In an ancestor UIViewController subclass's implementation (i.e. in the .m file) I have the following:

```
@interface GroupController (PrivateMethods)
    - (void) edit;
@end

- (void) edit {
    ... do something here ...
}
```

And of course in the corresponding .h file I do *not* declare the edit method. This was a random mistake on my part.

Should this work reliably anyways? What is the requirement for how to declare the method so that it receives the edit events?

BTW, I have reports that touching the "Edit" bar button item causes the app to crash every time it is touched, but only from a few of many thousands of users. I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "visibility" for Objective-C methods beyond where you stick the declaration at compile time.  At runtime, they are all the same.

First, action methods take an argument -- the sender.  Thus, your method really should be declared as:

```
- (IBAction)edit:(id)sender;
```

Note that `IBAction` is actually #defined to be `void`.  It is used by Interface Builder only.   Since you are doing things programmatically, you could use `void`.  Of course, that begs the question as to why you are doing things programmatically since that is almost always a waste of time, but... beyond the scope of this question.

In any case, yes, it should work reliably.  Whether or not a method is declared in a header makes zero difference at runtime.

Given that your crashes are rather intermittent,  it sounds more like you might have a memory management problem (or other latent crasher).   Did you build-and-analyze your code?   Got a crash log?

Comment: That's helpful info, thanks. Re. the crashes, build-and-analyze showed no problems, and no crash logs are available unfortunately. BTW, I think the (id)sender form of the method is 1 of 3 officially valid forms, with another being the no arg form. I think I saw that in an apple doc somewhere.

Comment: The (id) sender is the traditional form, most widely recognized, and generally recommended.  The no-arg form is a bit of a late coming hack.